# How to I access claims from another project? (AzureB2C)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication

I implemented the AzureB2C MVC Sample project into my solution so I could create a POC of its authentication services. The only issue is that I cant figure out how to authenticate users on my web project once the user is redirected back to us.

To elaborate, Project A contains this controller which authenticates the user -

```
public void SignUpSignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();
        return;
    }
    var username = "";
    foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)
    {
        if (claim.Type == "signInName")
        {
            username = "adtest3";
            Session["username"] = username; 
            break;
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect("https://SOMEWHERE IN PROJECT B/login/");
}
```

I'm able to access all claims without issue, but once the user is redirected to the login controller in PROJECT B, the claims are no longer accessible. First of all, how can I make them accessible? Why are they not accessible?

Answer (score 0):

In general, we would use the OpenID connect middleware and the cookie authentication middleware for integrating Azure AD B2C with ASP.NET MVC application. At this point, the OpenID connect middleware would use the cookies as the authentication type, and the **Claims** encoded in the token you will receive from Azure AD B2C tenant will be stored in a Cookie. Moreover, you could follow the github code sample [Azure AD B2C: Call an ASP.NET Web API from an ASP.NET Web App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi).

Based on your scenario, I assume that you could share cookie between your Project A (works as your custom authentication service) and Project B. If you share authentication cookie across multiple domains, you need to do some additional implementation. Details you could follow this [blog](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic).

I would prefer encode the Claims to a JWT token, then redirect to Project B, then you could decode the Claims and sign in the user with the Claims and redirect to the related page in your Project B.